# Power BI : Need to add columns to table visual based on slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-explorer, fact-table

I have a use-case wherein I am pulling a huge fact table from Azure Data Explorer and I need to create a table visual where there are few fixed columns in the visual and I need to provide a slicer with columns from the same fact table, this slicer will give a choice to the users to select columns and add that to the table visual on their choice.

I tried unpivoting the table but it is a large table and I am getting query limits exceeded message as I am using Azure Data Explorer as data source.

Can someone help me with this? I need to provide a slicer wherein users can select columns of their choice in table visual and the already selected columns by me doesn't get change, the new columns will just append to the existing table

Comment: why not limit the number of rows to something that fits the table visual (1,000 or 5,000 records)?

Comment: We are not getting error in table visual, we are getting this error during Unpivot in Transform Data / Edit Query

Comment: Can you provide more details that will allow us to reproduce the issue? I still don't understand why you need to limit the number of columns, is it because of perf issues or usability?

Comment: When I try to add all columns in the same visual, it is taking like years to load, which will lead to a performance issue

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible wit any other source.
Unpivoting a large set is not really an option
If you have a relatively small and responsible audience that you want to offer this option, you can give them edit right on the report and they will be able to add any columns they want.
The downside is that if they save the changes they made , it will change the report for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I definitely agree with it, is there a possibility that we can create a role which allows user to edit but not save the report? That can be good solution then, Thanks again!

Comment: You can vote for this idea at https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=770760c0-23f7-ea11-b5d9-281878a5ca29